# Is it possible to check for handle equality for a class that overloads eq?

Tags: matlab, overloading, handle, comparison-operators

My code has some handles for objects belonging to a third-party class that I can't modify. This class overloads `eq` so that rather than comparing whether the handles point to the same object, as the built-in version of `==` does, it does a different comparison based on the value of the input objects, irrespective of whether given two handles to the same object or not.

I explicitly want to check if the two handles point to the same object. I thought perhaps `builtin` would rescue me. But `builtin('eq',A,B)` just results in the error:

> Error using builtin
>
> Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'ThirdPartyClass'.

It seems like `builtin` only likes "pure" functions, and `handle.eq` is a special method of the `handle` class that is distinct from the builtin function `eq` that operates on pure functions.

Calling `eq` explicitly with the class name using `handle.eq(A,B)` doesn't work either - this yields the error

> No method 'eq' with matching signature found for class 'handle'.

Curiously, invoking the overload using the same syntax `ThirdPartyClass.eq(A,B)` yields a different error:

> The class ThirdPartyClass has no Constant property or Static method named 'eq'.

So it isn't exactly clear to me if `handle.eq(A,B)` is also necessarily interpreted as a call to a static method. But in this exact form at least it seems not to be a viable route to calling that (overloaded) regular method.

So have I been done over by the very inconsiderate design choice of the authors of this class? Or is there some way to access the method of the superclass that has been so recklessly overloaded? Or indeed, a way to achieve what `handle.eq` does from scratch (despite this being one of MATLAB's built-in functions that doesn't have its implementation visible in m-code)?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, is it possible to call `handle.eq(A,B)`? From a derived class, you typically do `method@parentClass()`, but I don't think that works from outside the class method.

Comment: Does `isequal(A, B)` work?

Comment: @CrisLuengo no - I actually had tried this but it doesn't work. I added details of this to the question. `method@parentClass()` is of course more straightforward - it results in the error `A base class method can only be called from the same method in a subclass.` which is what the documentation says explicitly about that syntax anyway.

Comment: @LuisMendo `handle.isequal` has fundamentally different behaviour to `handle.eq`. It checks the values of properties of `A` and `B` for equality irrespective of whether they belong to the same object instance, as documented in the Tips section of docs for both `eq` and `isequal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over the [list of public methods for `handle`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html#mw_a1057a14-11e6-487e-8c37-79678607622d) led to one solution that is viable in this case. Since `le` and `ge` are *not* overloaded in this class, the expression `A <= B & A >= B` has the same result as `A == B` does for handle classes without an overload on `eq`.

Comment: Of course this is reliant on the peculiarities of the class at hand, so I would still be interested in any solution that directly bypasses the effect of the method overload. I'll hold off accepting this answer for a few days in case a more satisfying answer comes in.